# Law of large numbers and converging functions of iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

I've been thinking about the following. I know from the law of large numbers that if $X_1,X_2,...$ is an infinite sequence of independent and identically distributed copies of integrable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \mathbb{E}[X]$$

Suppose we have a sequence of convex functions $f_1, f_2, ...$ converging pointwise to $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ from below i.e. $f_i \leq f$. Assume that $f_i(X_i)$ and $f(X)$ are integrable. Then is it true that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X_i) = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$$

holds?

**Edit:** I added convexity and integrability in the above.

Comment: Note that pointwise convergence is already too weak to imply $\mathbb{E}[f_i(X)] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$. I doubt that your claim holds.

Comment: That's certainly not true in general. Maybe you can tell us where you need such convergence or more properties of the functions and the distribution of $X$

Comment: Thank you. I made $f_i$ convex and added some lemmas in my post.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the first formula comes from a Monte Carlo assumption, not necessarily the law of large numbers

Comment: Actually the MC assumption seems to be roughly equivalent to the LLN, see: https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su14/lectures/cisewski_is.pdf

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at some theorems:

**Theorem 1:** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[f_i(X_i)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$

**Proof:** We know that the negative part of the function i.e. $\min\{0,f_i\}$ is Lipschitz continuous. Otherwise the epigraph of $f_i$ would not be convex. Using this and the fact that $f_i \leq f$,

$$|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X)| \leq \sup_{i=1,..,n}|f_i(0)| + C||X|| + |f(X)| $$

where $C = \sup\{C_1,C_2,...\}$ where $C_i$ Lipschitz constant for  $\min\{0,f_i\}$. Note that $C \leq \infty$ since $\min\{0,f_i\}$ converges pointwise  to $\min\{0, f\}$ which is Lipschitc continuous. Now using the dominated convergence theorem, we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[f_i(X)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$$

It is clear that $\mathbb{E}[f_i(X_i)] = \mathbb{E}[f_i(X)]$ and substituting this in the above limit gives the desired result. QED.

**Theorem 2:** $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X_i) = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ with probability one.

**Proof:** Define sequence $h_i(X_i) = f(X_i) - f_i(X_i)$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X_i) + h_i(X_i) = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ with probability one. To see this, note that
$f_i(X_i) + h_i(X_i)$ is iid copy of $f(X)$. Using the strong law of large numbers gives the result. Now we want to show
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h_i(X_i) = 0$ with probability one. Observe that $\lim_{i\to\infty} h_i(X_i) = 0$ almost surely because $f_i$ converges pointwise to $f$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(X_i) + 0 = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ with probability one. QED.